# Override method with generic type signature

Tags: f#

How can I override an abstract method with a generic type signature, and give it a more specific parameter type in a subclass?

```
type Rule() =
    abstract Core : 'T -> bool
    default _.Core _ = false

type Entity = {
    Name: string
    State: string
}

type Wisconsin() =
    inherit Rule()
    override _.Core (entity: Entity) =
        entity.State = "WI"
```

*SimpleMemberOverload.fsx(256,22): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
''a'
but here has type
'Entity'*

Comment: You can't. The base class says that the method accepts *any* type parameter. If you pass `Wisconsin` as a `Rule`, calling `Corer` should work with any type, not just `Entity`.

Comment: I noticed the file name SimpleMemberOverload.fsx in the error message, and I'm wondering whether there's confusion about overload and override. Those are two very different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't.** After all, saying a rule takes *any* 'T and then having such a rule taking only entities would violate the contract. What should a caller having a reference of type `Rule` pointing to an object of type `Wisconsin` expect if e.g. a `string` is passed to `Core`?

You could however define various rules like so:

```
type Rule<'T> () =
    abstract Core : 'T -> bool
    default _.Core _ = false

type Entity = {
    Name: string
    State: string
}

type Wisconsin() =
    inherit Rule<Entity>()
    override _.Core entity =
        entity.State = "WI"
```

meaning `Wisconsin` does not narrow the parameter type but now *is* a rule for/of entities.